# google places review api is not showing reviews/rating in the response

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am currently trying to use Places api for the getting place reviews, but it is not returning all the reviews/ratings for the place (as it show in maps/google+ for the same place).

for example-

If i get the review of "St Joseph's Hospital and Medical Center" google maps shows it has two reviews. but when i get the json response it doesn't show any reviews/ratings.

Thanks in advance
Shiv

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. We have lots of reviews on google but when I use the api I only get our company info and no reviews or ratings.  Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: They(google) have shifted all the google-places reviews to google plus.So u can crawl google plus to access comments.